# What is this floor material consisting of soft fibrous material covered by matte black layer?

Tags: insulation, subfloor, materials, screed

We are renovating an apartment in a house in Germany built in 1957.

I am unsure what kind of floor construction I am looking at. The concrete floor is covered by a soft brown fibrous layer about 1.5 cm thick, which is in turn covered by a hard matte black non-odorous layer with a gap of about 1 cm to the wall. What could these materials be? Could they contain asbestos?

[image]

Comment: Certainly prime time period for "yes, could contain asbestos" but as usual, the only way to **know** is to get it tested. The black layer is as much more more suspect as the fibrous layer, since "black mastic" was a very common asbestos containing material of the era.

Comment: Ignorance is bliss. "an apartment in a house" - so, tenets? That may change things, especially if you confirm that it's a hazardous material. Unoccupied? go nuts. - In the US, "Do-it-yourself asbestos removal is limited to residential property. If the property is commercial, a certified abatement professional must do the work." – [thespruce.com](https://www.thespruce.com/is-do-it-yourself-asbestos-removal-legal-1822434)

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be "Gussasphaltestrich" ("asphalt screed"?) on an insulation layer of coconut fibers. Lab analyses showed that the screed did not contain asbestos or PAH.